# Python Main Method Location Convention

Tags: python, program-entry-point, pep8

What are the official guidelines for the location of the main method in a Python program?

Should it be written first (at the top of the program), last (at the bottom), or is it just preferential? I read through PEP8 and couldn't find anything.

Comment: You probably want to have it at the bottom, to make sure that at the time you are calling main, your definitions are already initialized.

Comment: There is no official recommendation.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga this should be an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no official guidelines referring to this.

Comment: As long as the line calling the `main()` function occurs after all functions are declared it doesn't matter what order they are declared in. The functions will be recorded for use by the time you get to calling them inside `main()`. You won't get a `NameError`.

Comment: Of course, I should have pointed that out. I didn't interpret the question correctly (it's 4AM, cut me some slack) so I thought they were asking where to call the main method or something - which of course would be after all the other functions are declared.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever is most useful for someone to read first should go first.

Often, this is going to be some kind of "main" method. It describes the flow of the program. It will give developers a quick way of figuring out what is happening and where to look for things they want.

But I can envisage cases where it's not explicitly the `main()` method. Maybe the `main()` method just spins off some threads and it's what's inside it that counts. Maybe `main()` just does a bunch of argument parsing, and then calls another function. Maybe `main()` is just boilerplate.